# DictReader hangs on reading large CSV file until touch command executed on the file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, freeze

I have a script I'm using which generates .CSV output file, which afterwards I iterate over and validate the results.

Now everything works fine as long as the .CSV file isn't too large. When the script runs for long duration it generates a .CSV file about **~500-600MB** which I'm reading with *DictReader*.

If the file is large, *DictReader* hangs on reading the file. It was stuck.

I did **strace** on the python process, and the result was

```
[tux@box ~]# strace -p 1481
Process 14881 attached
futex(0x213c420, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL
```

The process is waiting for something. Then a college suggested doing `touch file_name` because it can affect my situation, and he was right. After I executed `touch` on the file and ran strace again, I saw the lock was released

```
[tux@box ~]# strace -p 1481
Process 1481 attached
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {0, 934636}) = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, {1, 0})     = 0 (Timeout)
...
```

- What has happened here, that `touch` a file name caused my python program to resume running? (I assume the tool which creates this .CSV maybe hasn't done writing it, when the DictReader tried to read the file, but I'm unsure)
- Is there a way to validate the .CSV file is ready for reading? (I already check it exists using the `os` module, I need something more sophisticated to make sure the file has no open `fd` to it or somthing similar)

Comment: could we see your code? (if not too big)

Comment: Are you using threading at all?

Comment: Also, is this on Linux? What's the kernel version? It's unlikely to be a Python specific issue, by the way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, the app generating the CSV is multi threaded, but my reader isn't. It's centos 7, I'll check the kernel version

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I narrowed it down to the issue, this is part of a large system. The tool creating the CSV is a 3rd party, and works in multi threaded env. Anything specific you can think of?

Comment: is your python script running _while_ the other script creates the file? that could be an issue. Else it isn't an issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the python script starts the 3rd party app which writes the csv. Then once it's done the scripts resumes and reading the file (after checking it exists)

Comment: @Vinny: so a child process is involved? I think that's significant.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, it is. I will add a check if the child process is dead before reading the file. I believe this will solve the issue. By the way - is there a better solution verifying a file is ready for reading?

Comment: @MartijnPieters the kernel version is 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64. I have added a test to verify the child process is closed before accessing the file. I believe this would work, but do you have any assumption why when I used `touch` my python script resumed?

Comment: @Vinny: I have no assumptions; I was just going by what I found through some Google research. Perhaps the subprocess is stuck and the touch clears that.